# Spring boot version upgrade from 1.4.5.RELEASE to 2.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade my springboot version from 1.4.5 to 2.0.7. I have updated the spring-boot-starter-parent, and its cloud dependency to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix. Also spring cloud version to Finchley.SR2.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
 8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<springfox-version>2.5.0</springfox-version>
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent> 
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config- 
    client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I'm getting error at starting tomcat context. Following are my logs from the console.

> Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new
>   driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is
>   automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver
>   class is generally unnecessary. 2019-01-02 16:42:59.780  INFO 14180
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] jdbc.audit                               : null. DataSource.unwrap(class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) returned 
>   2019-01-02 16:42:59.855 ERROR 14180 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : /***Error starting Tomcat
>   context. Exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message:
>   Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in
>   class path resource***/
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]:
>   Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]:
>   Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d404129]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's
>   singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DataSourceSpy cannot be cast to
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig 2019-01-02 16:43:00.016  INFO 14180 ---
>   [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping
>   service [Tomcat]

Comment: Update your question with code snippet and pom.xml

Comment: Yes added the parts of pom.xml, where I made changes

Comment: Please add application.properties or config file, because if you are adding any dependency, you need to provide some of the mandatory configurations.

Comment: I have not added any changes in my application.properties file. I have done a few changes(removed deprecated code)

Comment: Try 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest' instead of spring-data-rest-webmvc. It seems spring-data-rest-webmvc's verson should be 3.0.12.RELEASE to work with spring-boot 2.0.7